# How to enable swipe to delete on custom UITableViewCell Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I need to add the "swipe to delete" feature on my UITableView, I tried with the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
           editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [indexProdotti removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unhandled editing style! %ld", (long)editingStyle);
    }
}
```

The problem is that there is only a limited space I have to swipe in order to show the delete button, the rest of the cell if swiped gives no result.. Am I missing something in my implementation?

Comment: by clicking, do you mean swiping?

Comment: yeah sorry, i've edited my question

Comment: If the content of your cell is something like a scrollview, webview or other components, which use the touches themselfs, it will not work.

Comment: you may have added some other gesture recognizer, which is being recognized instead of the swipe.

Comment: no I have no gesture recognizer on my class, and the cell has only 2 UILabel and an ImageView

Comment: have you added any gestures to other classes? or are you using any apis that have implemented any gestures? this happened to me once when i was using a side menu that the user could access by swiping from the middle of the view.

Comment: Have you added a button (like 'Edit') in your table view so that when the user taps on it the table becomes editable and cells can be deleted?

Comment: Also, I think you should implement `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`